# RPi 3 ad-hoc network to configure WiFi credentials

Tags: wifi, connection, home-automation, wifi-direct

I need help finding a proper tutorial or project that can achieve the following:

I want to create an ad-hoc network that could be used to configure the RPi 3 to connect to an existing wifi network that requires a password. To achieve that, I would want to set up a web server on the Raspberry Pi that serves up a configuration page. The configuration page could display a list of all the wireless networks in range. Users could connect up to the ad-hoc network, view the configuration web page, select their personal wireless network, and then enter the appropriate network credentials. The Raspberry Pi could then switch to the newly configured network through which it could get access to the internet or other resources.

Answer (score -1):

You could try [this](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/04/22/raspberry-pi-wireless-communication/) for the ad-hoc config. And [this](http://slicepi.com/creating-an-ad-hoc-network-for-your-raspberry-pi/%0A) to enable switching after you have edited the copy file with the user supplied password details.

Comment: Link only answers are not ideal, a little more detail in your question would be great.