# Is there a off the shelf solution to set WiFi credentials via RPi's hot spot?

Tags: wifi

I'm looking for a ready to use solution which will do the following:

1. Raspberry Pi turns on in a new WiFi network (no credentials configured yet)
2. RPi turns on its WiFi hotspot allowing user to connect with a phone or any other device
3. User loads a web configuration tool from the RPi with all networks available
4. User sets the credentials via web configuration tool
5. RPi reboots (if needed) and use just set credentials to connect to the network

I don't see any reason why this couldn't be done. But I believe that this should be already done by someone earlier.

I have read some related questions ([1](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/130853/send-wifi-credentials-wirelessly-to-a-rpi), [2](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45446/rpi-3-ad-hoc-network-to-configure-wifi-credentials), [3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/133890/how-do-i-send-users-wifi-credentials-to-my-rpi-wirelessly)) but there is no answer.

Comment: *"I believe that this should be already done by someone earlier."* -> I'm not saying it hasn't, but an issue might be that it is already trivially do-able using ssh, which is fairly universal, then of course you have to add/change a few lines in some config files.  Anyone who *could* implement the web interface would certainly be familiar with this, so unless they were developing a commercial product, there's not much motive to bother.

Comment: Let me Google that for you: [`raspberry Pi hotspot configuration tool`](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=raspberry+Pi+hotspot+configuration+tool)